# How to use multiple templates in Portia / Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, portia

I have successfully installed Portia based on the following tutorial:

http://www.akashjaindxb.com/2014/05/12/install-setup-and-use-portia-webcrawler/

and everything is working perfectly.
However the site I want to spider has different layouts for
certain items, thus I require multiple templates.

The above tutorial mentions that multiple templates can be used
but doesn't explain how to actually use multiple templates when crawling.

Does someone know how to instruct PORTIACRAWL to use multiple templates.
Thank you very much in advance.